# docker-compose: Is there any way to prevent `php-fpm` to be started until `db` has end?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - sql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    httpd:
        build: docker/httpd
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes_from:
            - php-fpm
    php-fpm:
        build: docker/php-fpm
        depends_on:
            - db
volumes:
    sql_data:
        external: true
```

The container `php-fpm` should run some scripts to create the schema and load fake data only if `db` has been started and DB has been created successfully. Currently `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate` is doing the following:

- Creating network `dockerpyrocms_default` with the default driver
- Building `php-fpm`
- Building `httpd`
- Creating `dockerpyrocms_db_1`
- Creating `dockerpyrocms_php-fpm_1`
- Creating `dockerpyrocms_httpd_1`

But because the DB hasn't be created as such point then `dockerpyrocms_php-fpm_1` is exiting with code ` and the cause is it can connect to the DB:

```
php-fpm_1  |   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   
php-fpm_1  |   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = pyrocms and table_name = default_migrations)  
php-fpm_1  |   [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
php-fpm_1  |   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Apparently "depends_on" is sort of useless because Docker doesn't know when the container is "ready", it only knows when it has been started.

Can I get some advice on this? Any ideas in how to fix this issue?

Here is [the repo](https://github.com/reypm/docker-pyrocms) with files and instructions.

> Note: Such problem only happen if MySQL image was already pulled and there wasn't any changes. If you run this for first time then it'll works if you run in a second time it will fails.

Comment: Am i right understand the question "How can i force php wait until db was started up" ?

Comment: @BukharovSergey kind of but yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in Docker Compose itself:

> With Compose 1.10, it is now possible to indicate you want a
> dependency to wait for another container to be “healthy” (i.e. its
> healthcheck advertises a successful state) before starting.

Ex:

```yaml
version: '2.1'
services:
    web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
        db:
        condition: service_healthy
        redis:
        condition: service_started
    redis:
    image: redis
    db:
    image: redis
    healthcheck:
        test: "exit 0"
```

Now my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```yaml
version: '2.1'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        healthcheck:
            test: "exit 0"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - sql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    httpd:
        build: docker/httpd
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes_from:
            - php-fpm
    php-fpm:
        build: docker/php-fpm
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
volumes:
    sql_data:
        external: true
```

And it works as expected. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dependson) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck).

Comment: No longer works:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on
"Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.
The depends_on option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file."

Comment: Docs mentioned by Richard can now be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wait for it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it).

> wait-for-it.sh is a pure bash script that will wait on the availability of a host and TCP port. It is useful for synchronizing the spin-up of interdependent services, such as linked docker containers. Since it is a pure bash script, it does not have any external dependencies.

How to use?
add [etntrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) in php-fpm container.
`entrypoint` can look like this script:

```
wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -t 60
# some code interacted with database 
# will executed only when database is started up
```